# find owner of a file and return the files that matched

Tags: python, windows, security, filesystems

```py
import os,stat
from os import walk
from pathlib import Path

path = "C:/Users/HP/Desktop"
owner = "DEEPTHI\HP"

for root, dirs, files in walk(path, topdown=False):
    for name in files:
```

Here I have to list all the files that match under the owner "DEEPTHI\HP" in windows.

Comment: You can get the owner via [`GetNameSecurityInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/A/nf-aclapi-getnamedsecurityinfow), which is available in PyWin32's win32security module. If the filesystem doesn't support security, such as FAT32, then the owner will be "\Everyone". (Keep in mind the file is not necessarily on the "C:" volume. You may have traversed a mountpoint or symlink.) Do you want that to match the target owner?

Comment: FYI, your string literal for the owner should escape the backslash. Either use `"DEEPTHI\\HP"` or `r"DEEPTHI\HP"`.